# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para crear una cadena a partir de otra cadena?

Tags: java

Tengo una clase en la cual tengo declarado tres variables, `String cadena` , `String palabra []`, `int i`.

Mi ejercicio consiste en introducir a través de la variable `cadena` una frase por teclado, y crear frases diferentes a partir de este, jugando con las posiciones.

Para ello he creado un `array` donde voy almacenando en cada posición del `array` las palabras separadas por un `split(" ")`. Y he intentado jugar con las posiciones del `array` para crear otras frases pero mi resultado no esta siendo correcto.

He probado a utilizar una función `random()` para que me genere posiciones aleatorias pero no veo la forma de aplicarlo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MainII {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Dime una frase");
        String cadena = sc.nextLine();//Frase introducida por teclado
        String palabra [] = cadena.split(" ");//Array donde almanceno una palabra por posicion
        int i = 0; //contador que se incrementa para recorrer la longitud de la cadena

        for(String mipalabra:palabra) { 
            System.out.println(palabra[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar el método [`Collections.shuffle(list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-)

```
List<String> palabras = Arrays.asList(cadena.split(" "));
Collections.shuffle(palabras);
String nuevaFrase = String.join(" ",  palabras);
```

Comment: Buena sugerencia @Roberto.

Answer (score 4):

Si lo que quieres es de una frase original sacar otra frase con las palabras aleatorias del array, que creo que es lo que estás pidiendo, no vas mal encaminado con ese procedimiento que quieres usar, te dejo como lo haría yo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MainII {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Dime una frase");
        String cadena = sc.nextLine();//Frase introducida por teclado
        String palabra [] = cadena.split(" ");//Array donde almanceno una palabra por posicion
        int i = 0; //contador que se incrementa para recorrer la longitud de la cadena

        for(String mipalabra:palabra) {
            double numero =  Math.random() * palabra.length;
            System.out.println(palabra[(int) numero]);
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

El metodo `random()` lo que hace es generar un número aleatorio entre 0 y 1, pero sin llegar realmente al 1, con infinidad de decimales. Lo que he hecho ha sido crear una variable que almacene el número aleatorio, con decimales incluidos, para luego pasárselo a la posición de array pero casteandolo a int, que me va a sacar un número aleatorio entre 0 y la longitud del array.

Suponiendo que escribo "hola que ase" de frase inicial, la longitud del array va a ser de 3, pero el metodo `random()` me va a sacar un número entre 0 y 2 por que nunca va a llegar a 3, como mucho llegaría a 2,999999999.

En realidad el contador i lo podrías suprimir, no hace nada. Se me ha olvidado quitarlo.

Comment: No es exactamente la salida que estoy buscando pero me puede servir como referencia para enfocar una posible solución. La idea es por ejemplo "Hola que tal"  pues crear "Hola que tal" , "que tal Hola" , "tal Hola que", "que Hola tal". Pero muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Dado a tu comentario, en una de las otras respuestas, he tratado de dar con lo que requieres:

> (...)La idea es por ejemplo "Hola que tal" pues crear "Hola que tal" , "que
>   tal Hola" , "tal Hola que", "que Hola tal".(...)

He creado una nueva clase llamada **`ControladorPalabra`** con dos métodos estáticos `devuelveCantCombinaciones` y `devuelveCombinaciones`, para que se viera más ordenado:

```java
public class ControladorPalabra{
    //básicamente devuelve factorial que es igual cantidad de combinaciones posibles
    // que tiene una frase dada la cantidad de palabras que esta posee
    public static int devuelveCantCombinaciones(List<String> frase){
        int combinaciones = 1; //debe de empezar en 1
        int espacios = frase.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < frase.size(); i++){
            combinaciones *= espacios;
            espacios--;
        }
        return combinaciones; //retorna el factorial del largo de la lista entregada
    }
    //devuelve un ArrayList con las combinaciones de frases posibles
    public static ArrayList<String> devuelveCombinaciones(List<String> frase){
        ArrayList<String> posibilidades = new ArrayList<>(); //nuevas frases posibles
        int cantidad = devuelveCantCombinaciones(frase);


        while(posibilidades.size() < cantidad){
            //frase con orden random
            Collections.shuffle(frase);
            String nuevaFrase = String.join(" ",  frase);
            if(!posibilidades.contains(nuevaFrase)){
                posibilidades.add(nuevaFrase);
            }
        }

        return  posibilidades; //retorna el ArrayList con las posibilidades
    }
}
```

`devuelveCantCombinaciones` calcula la cantidad de posibilidades de distintas frases que se pueden obtener a partir de una frase dada, este calcula la cantidad de palabras que posee, y saca su factorial, [te dejo este documento](http://www.unavarra.es/digitalAssets/124/124059_100000Permutaciones-y-combinaciones.pdf) donde lo explica mucho mejor.

Cito parte del texto:

> El factorial de `n`, escrito `n!`, es el producto de los enteros entre 1 y `n`; así, el factorial de 6 es
>
> `6!= 6×5× 4×3× 2×1= 720 .`
>
> Definimos 0!=1,
>   principalmente porque como ya hemos visto el factorial de `n` es igual
>   al número de formas de ordenar `n` elementos distintos.

`devuelveCombinaciones`, recibe la frase fragmentada por palabra en un `List` de tipo `String`, se tiene un ciclo `while` que no parará hasta que el `ArrayList` a devolver tenga la misma cantidad de combinaciones posibles que entrega el método `devuelveCantCombinaciones`, una vez dentro del ciclo, se compara con un `if` si es que el `ArrayList` a devolver contiene la frase creada de forma aleatoria por el método `shuffle()`, el cual, según la [información oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) "*al azar permuta la lista especificada utilizando una fuente predeterminada de aleatoriedad*", si es que no se contiene lo guarda.

En el método `main`:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Dime una frase");
String cadena = sc.nextLine();//Frase introducida por teclado
List<String> palabra = Arrays.asList(cadena.split(" ")); //cambiado de String[] a List<String>
int i = 0; //contador que se incrementa para recorrer la longitud de la cadena

//recorre el arraylist devuelto por el método
for (String frase : ControladorPalabra.devuelveCombinaciones(palabra)){
     i++; //cantidad de posibilidades
     System.out.println("Posibilidad "+ i + " = " + frase);
}
```

### **Resultado ejemplo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Captura del gif anterior

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> PD: para frases que son muy largas el devolver las posibilidades
>   tomará un tiempo. por ejemplo una frase que contenga 8 palabras en su
>   interior, son 40320 posibilidades de frases distintas, en mi caso se
>   demoró 1.30 minutos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fuentes:

[-  Factorial de un número](http://lineadecodigo.com/java/factorial-de-un-numero/)

[-  Permutaciones y combinaciones](http://www.unavarra.es/digitalAssets/124/124059_100000Permutaciones-y-combinaciones.pdf)